# NSTableView - programatic display of values in a long table view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstableview, nscell

Ok, so I am creating an iTunes overlay for a client. My question is, with a given index, how am I able to move the displayed cells/cells in a row to a specific entry in the table view, programatically.

In other words, replicating iTunes when you are on a playlist it jumps in its table view to the next song if the table view (strictly the playlist) has enough entries in it to warrant this jump!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See NSTableView's [-scrollRowToVisible:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/scrollRowToVisible:).

Comment: you are a star, do not know how I missed it, thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: :-) Don't forget to tip your waitress (by voting/marking as answered) if it worked for you.

Comment: yeah, the method worked just fine, just need to get my index variable in correctly, which is turning out to be the issue now...!